# Don't know how to build task 'recipe_test.rb'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task, rakefile, rake-test

I know same question is asked before but those were totally different scenarios than mine . I have a `.rb` file in my `rails_app/test/integration`

 
**recipe_test.rb**

```
require "test_helper"

class RecipeFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :recipes
  test 'create recipes' do
    https! # sign in emulation
    curry = recipes(:curry)
    get '/recipes/new'
    assert_response :success

    post_via_redirect '/recipes/new', title: recipes(:curry).title
    assert_equal '/recipes', path
    assert_equal 'Create Recipe', flash[:notice]

    https!(false) # sign out emulation
    get '/recipes'
    assert_response :success
    assert assigns(:recipes) # fetch out inst var :recipes (in controller)
  end
end
```

And a `test/fixture/recipe_test.yml`

```
curry:
  title: Curry
  food_preference_id: 1
  food_type: 1
  cuisine_id: 1
  servings: 1
  cooking_time: 1
  level_of_difficulty: Easy
  ingredients: Onions Tomatoes Salt Oil
  procedure: Heat Oil Chop Onions,
             tomatoes and Salt to it.
```

Here is my `test/helper_test.rb`

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
integration tests
  fixtures :all
end
```

Now when i do `rake test recipe_test.rb --trace`

It give me following error

```
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:run (first_time)
** Execute test:run
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'recipe_test.rb'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `rake` task is invalid. [Here's a list of proper rake test tasks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rake-tasks-for-running-your-tests).

You just need

```
rake test
```

For your `recipe_test`, you can also do `rake test:integration`

Comment: Eeeeeeeeeh , wasted 4 hours due to my weak R&D on rake .

Comment: Thanks a lot friend!